# Omit function props from the dependencies list in React.useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following block of code:

```
function foo({ bar, func }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    func(bar)
  }, [func, bar])

  ....
}
```

Is this an anti pattern to include `func` within the dependencies list for `React.useEffect`? I'm under the impression that the function definition for `func` almost never changes. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the value of `func` that is obviously initialized in the parent component

But assuming `func` is set to a constant function that will never change (which is mostly the case) then no need to add it here, you could just leave `bar` and remove `func` from the second argument of `useEffect`

However the bad practice here, in your code if `func` is set to a function that increments `bar` for example

```
const func = (bar) => bar + 1;
```

This will end up triggering the `useEffect` infinitely, because everytime `bar` changes the `useEffect` will be triggered and increment `bar` again and so on.

#### In case you're wondering if `func` can ever be changed

I'll give you an example parent component that `func` will change on a button click.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const increment = bar => bar+1;
    const decrement = bar => bar-1;

    const [func, setFunc] = useState(increment);

    return <div>
         //When this button is clicked, `func` value will be changed
         <button onClick={() => setFunc(decrement)}/>

         // This is your component
         <foo func={func}/>
    </div>
}
```